# Is android manifest "persistent=true" for preloaded app still applied after an app update?

Tags: android, preload, persistent

I'm trying to update my app (which is system app(preloaded)) via Google Play Store.
I've found that when preloaded app is updated, new apk file is placed in /data folder, unlike the first apk for preload (/system folder).

In the manifest application setting, I've set 
`persistent='true'` to retain process from kill.
But this setting is applied only when the app is an system app.

I'm just worried about since the updated app file is in /data folder,
after the update, `persistent='true'` is not applied.

Does android still recognize the updated preload app as system app, and apply `persistent='true'` setting correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell dumpsys package packagename
```

Check the FLAG if there is SYSTEM in it , it would be ok.